# Get YouTube Comments URL?

Tags: php, youtube

The comments on a video page on youtube are an iframe from Google+.

Is it possible to get the URL of the iframe?

The URL is long and i can't see a pattern in it:

```
https://apis.google.com/u/0/b/112383300030545024301/wm/4/_/widget/render/comments?usegapi=1&first_party_property=YOUTUBE&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DnCgQDjiotG0&owner_id=L8ZULXASCc1I_oaOT0NaOQ&query=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DnCgQDjiotG0&stream_id=UCL8ZULXASCc1I_oaOT0NaOQ&substream_id=nCgQDjiotG0&view_type=FILTERED&width=590&youtube_video_acl=PUBLIC&viewer_id=UC8JjcqxbRmTpP6P-yRPs9_w&hl=de_DE&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&search=%3Fv%3DnCgQDjiotG0&hash=&gsrc=1p&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.gapi.en.tj_0ZMtt37Y.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTNq9BUbpcVyrrQw8r5GUHIc2HQyDQ#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Confirsttimeplusonepromo%2Conthumbsup%2Contimestampclicked%2Conready%2Conallcommentsclicked&id=I0_1394888331421&parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&pfname=&rpctoken=30117793
```

You can't get the URL via the API and I've already tried to parse the HTML and get the URL, it didn't work, although it should work.

Comment: Are you trying to get this from HTML Source ? If so, you can make use of `DOMXPath` and retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pattern:

```
https://apis.google.com/u/0/wm/4/_/widget/render/comments?width={WIDTH}&first_party_property=YOUTUBE&view_type={FILTER}&sort=1&page_size={COMMENTS_PER_PAGE}&stream_id={CHANNEL_ID}&substream_id={VIDEO_ID}&query=http://youtu.be/{VIDEO_ID}
```

Use your `{CHANNEL_ID}` and `{VIDEO_ID}` and
these values for `{FILTER}`: FILTERED, FILTERED_POSTMOD, UNFILTERED.
Maximum value for `{COMMENTS_PER_PAGE}` = 100

You can subscribe to iframe postMessages and get some useful info, like height of the widget after rendering. Still looking for dynamic update for these values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the youtube API v2 to fetch comments

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments